# Initializing a struct within a struct?

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, initialization, variable-assignment

So I have the following two structures

```
typedef struct clienttable {
    vartable head;
    vartable tail;
} clienttable;

typedef struct vartable {
    int tableid;
    int randominfo;
    struct vartable *next;
} vartable;
```

and I want to initizalite them like this.

```
clienttable *maintable;
maintable = (clienttable *) malloc (sizeof( clienttable));
maintable->head = {.tableid = 10, .randominfo=NULL, .next=NULL};
```

but when I go to compile I keep getting a

```
expected expression before { token
```

error. I have tried just `{10,NULL}` as well to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, will I need to `malloc` both the `clientable` and all the tables within the client table, or will just `malloc`ing the one work?

Comment: Using C99,C11 or something older?

Comment: I think 99, but I can switch to something else if necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

This

```
maintable->head = ...
```

is not an initialisation but an assignment.

This

```
... = {.tableid = 10, .randominfo=NULL, .next=NULL};
```

however can only be used for initialisation.

So change the latter to this

```
... = (vartable) {.tableid = 10, .randominfo=0, .next=NULL};
```

an assignment using a compound literal.

---

> ... will I need to malloc both the clientable and all the tables within the client table, or will just mallocing the one work?

Not really sure what you are referring to by "*all the tables*", but by allocating a `clienttable`-typed variable you allocate the memory for both its members `head`and `tail`. You do *not* allocate memory for what `head` and `tail`'s members `next`  are pointing to.